# recursively extend json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I have a recursive json structure which contains some properties and a node containing the children, which is the same format as deep as it needs to be. The example below isn't complete or the same as my data, but it shows the rough structure.

```
[{"page":{
    title: "my title 1",
    children: [
        {"page":{
            title: "my title 2",
            children: [ ... ]
        },{"page":{
            title: "my title 3",
            children: [ ... ]
        },{"page":{
            title: "my title 4",
            children: [
                {"page": {
                    title: "my other title",
                    children: [ ... ]
                }]
        },{"page":{
            title: "my title 5",
            children: [ ... ]
        }]
        ... etc
```

I would like to extend the object so that every "page" object gets a new set of properties - e.g. say I want to add `{score: 5.3, theme:"moody"}` to every "page", so that they all get the properties, such that if I were to stringify the json object each page would then have these properties added.

```
{"page":{title:"some title", score: 5.3, theme: "moody"}}
```

Is there a way to recursively extend json/object structures, preferably in jQuery?

Comment: Create a fiddle with an actual valid object we can play with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, what you have is an array of objects. An array is a native JS object (an augmented instance of `Object`, in fact). There is no such thing as *a JSON object* in JS, since JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation.
It's a format that is often used to transfer data, but well-formed JSON is well-formed JS literal notation. So much so that you could just `eval` a JSON string, but ***whatever you do, don't***. [More details can be found here](http://json.org/)

Be that as it may, any solution you get will be a JavaScript solution, seeing as jQ is JavaScript... Everything you do in JS works in jQ, every statement involving jQ you write evaluates to a series of function calls and other wizardry that makes up the jQ toolkit, all of which are written in plain 'ol VanillaJS anyway.

However, back to your question. Looking at your structure, I think I'm right in saying that each `children` property is an array, containing objects, that (may) have a `page` property. This property will have an object assigned to it. These are all assumptions on my part, but I get the impression that this is the case here. That means that, to *extend* this object, a simple map-callback-function will suffice:

```
yourArray = yourArray.map(function ext(obj)
{//named callback function, does not pollute global scope
   obj.title = "title";
   obj.score = 5.3;
   if (obj.children instanceOf Array)
   {//recursively apply callback
       obj.children = obj.children.map(ext);//reference to current callback function
   }
   return obj;//return altered object
});
```

This maps each array, assigning properties to the objects, then it checks if there is a `children` property, that is also an array, and applies the same callback function to map that array, thus rendering this mapping a recursive one.
Because we're dealing with objects here, the `return obj` statement is actually optional, because objects are references:

```
yourArray.map(function ext(obj)
{//no assignment
   obj.title = "title";
   obj.score = 5.3;
   if (obj.children instanceOf Array)
   {
       obj.children = obj.children.map(ext);
   }
});
```

Would work just as well
Using jQuery's `extend` method, you can shorten this code a tad, but not by much (1 line, in fact), of course:

```
yourArray = yourArray.map(function ext(obj)
{
   $.extend(obj, {title: 'title',score: 5.3});
   if (obj.children instanceOf Array)
   {
       obj.children = obj.children.map(ext);
   }
   return obj;
});
```

Or, even more jQ flavour:

```
$.each(yourArray, function ext(i, obj)
{
    $.extend(obj, {title: 'title', score: 5.3});
    if (obj.children instanceof Array)
    {
        $.each(obj.children(ext));
    }
});
```

But as you can see, in terms of readability, and code compactness, the differences are rather minor. All jQ does here, really, is slow you down, to be brutally honest.
Because `$.extend` requires an object as second param, I have to construct an object literal on each invocation of the callback. I can not use an object, assigned to a variable that resides in a higher scope because, as mentioned before: objects are never copied, only the references to them are. using a variable from a higher scope would make the code more error prone:

```
var extendObj = {title: 'title', score: 4};
yourArray = yourArray.map(function ext(obj)
{
   $.extend(obj, extendObj);
   if (obj.children instanceOf Array)
   {
       obj.children = obj.children.map(ext);
   }
   return obj;
});
```

This would work perfectly, *but*:

```
var extendObj = {title: 'title', score: 4, deep:{another: 'object'}};
```

would require a deep clone:

```
$.extend(true, obj, extendObj);
```

Which, if you were to forget/omit that, changing the property of `deep` through one instance, would mean that all other instances reflect that same change, too... not ideal

Comment: +1 This is a good thorough answer but I think you might want to rephrase some things in the first paragraph to make it a tad more readable. Also - JSON is not just and acronym - it's a format with a specification, not all JS object literals are valid JSON objects. For example `[1,2,3,]` is a valid JS array object literal but not a valid JSON array.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: righty-o. I've expanded the opening paragraph a bit, clarifying a thing or 2, adding a link to json.org. I'm off to lunch now, but I hope, with the edits made, this answer is clear enough for all...

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for explaining the different methods.